# Eclipse BIRT Hyperlink drill-through fail to get correct url

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, hyperlink, birt

I am currently developing report tools using birt v4.6.0. But I failed when I try to add hyperlink to one of the .rptdesign file.

Everything worked fine when I deployed my web project on tomcat server. However, when I try to click the hyperlink function of the master report, the server threw exception that the linked rptde[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRYqh.jpg)sign file cannot be found. And I found the below strange directory in my eclipse console:

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot find C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/SummaryReportDetails.rptdesign

It seems that it cannot find my .rptdesign properly and I have no idea why it is pointed to the temp folder instead of my workspace....

About setting in hyperlink, the field of master report was linked to the detail report with required parameters. And all of my rptdesign file are placed in report resource folder in my workspace.

I used eclipse neon IDE for birt development to develop the web project, tomcat v7.0 as the server and firefox as my browser. Dont know if it can help or not.....thanks a lot

I have searched many related resources for weeks but still fail to solve this problems. Please kindly help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URI option instead. Master and the secondary(after drill upon clicking on hyperlink) rptDesign files must be in same location/folder. This worked for me.

[image]